# Memory limit error when merging data frames using reduce

Tags: r

I have a list of 67 data frames.  Each data frame has two columns, the first is named "Material" and the second is named a month and year.  Every data frame has the same name for the first column, but no two data frames have the same name for the second column.

```
> head(str(fy16_list))
List of 67
 $ April_FY11    :'data.frame': 1559 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Material  : chr [1:1559] "622-5129-105" "622-5129-109" "622-5129-203" "622-5129-223" ...
  ..$ April_FY11: chr [1:1559] "1 " NA "(3)" NA ...
 $ April_FY12    :'data.frame': 1721 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Material  : chr [1:1721] "622-5129-021" "622-5129-105" "622-5129-109" "622-5129-203" ...
  ..$ April_FY12: chr [1:1721] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ April_FY13    :'data.frame': 1189 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Material  : chr [1:1189] "122000-F15SA_1" "122000-F15SA_2" "987-9705-001" "822-1867-001" ...
  ..$ April_FY13: chr [1:1189] NA NA "-15" "15" ...
```

The list is 5.2Mb in size so it really isn't very big at all, but for some reason when I do:

```
mydf <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), mylist)
```

I wait for like 5-10min and then get an error message that says I've reached my memory limit!

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 88.7 Mb 
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.frame`(x, c(m$xi, if (all.x) m$x.alone), c(by.x,  ... :
  Reached total allocation of 8078Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In `[.data.frame`(x, c(m$xi, if (all.x) m$x.alone), c(by.x,  ... :
  Reached total allocation of 8078Mb: see help(memory.size)
# The warning message repeats 12 times...
```

The data frame I've created is 8Gb in size!  I have no idea why this is happening. I tried

```
mydf <- reshape::merge_all(mylist)
```

But the same thing happens.

Everything works smoothly when I do

```
mylist <- mylist[1:10]
mydf <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), mylist)
```

So I'm thinking that this code just is not scalable, but honestly 5.2Mb seems pretty small as I've worked with lists over 300Mb in r before.

Any suggestions for getting this to work?

Comment: It's likely that your material column has duplicated elements, in which case the merge will increase the size tremendously due to all possible combinations of rows with duplicated material.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!